# Nest.js - process.env.npm_package_description does not return correct value

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, nestjs, package.json

When running Nest.js application `process.env.npm_package_description` returns

```
[Nest](https://github.com/nestjs/nest) framework TypeScript starter repository.
```

instead of description that is in `package.json`

Comment: How does that value get populated? On a `nest new` project I can't get a return for `console.log(process.env.npm_package_description)`

Comment: I just created a new project using `nest n name` added a bunch of modules controllers and services and that is it. I am reading this value inside src/main.ts

Comment: I am using yarn btw

Comment: Versions: Node.js: v18.6.0; Npm: 8.14.0; Yarn: 1.22.19; Nest.js: 9.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I don't know the why yet, will update when I can find the code, but it *looks* like what is happening is that when the `description` in your `package.json` is empty then `process.env.npm_package_description` gets set to the first line (or close to it) of your README.

- `pnpm` seems to not do this.
- `npm` brings back a value like `<p align="center">   <a href="http://nestjs.com/" target="blank"><img src="https://nestjs.com/img/logo-small.svg" width="200" alt="Nest Logo" /></a> </p>`
- `yarn` brings back a value of `[Nest](https://github.com/nestjs/nest) framework TypeScript starter repository.` (this is the first line under the `## Description` tag in the README, might be related)

Comment: Thank you very much <3 In my case it happens even when I place a text inside description. It is necessary to me because I want to have a single source of truth when it comes description and version (for example to place it in swagger (openApi) configuration object)

Comment: Make sure you restart the process entirely instead of doing a hot reload. The package manager needs to read the description field when it __first__ runs the script to properly populate the field

Comment: Oh, you are right, now it is working, thank you very much <3